# Symfony 2 Persist data into MongoDB using DoctrineMongoDBBundle

Tags: mongodb, symfony-2.8

I want to insert data into MongoDB with Symfony 2 using DoctrineMongoDBBundle. I have followed [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html) tutorial from Symfony Documentation. In my controller class i have this function

> ```
>   *public function createAction()
>        {
>             $product = new Product();
>             $product->setName('Apple Juice');
>             $product->setPrice('19.99');
>             $product1 = new Product();
>             $product1->setName('Orange Juice');
>             $product1->setPrice('19.98');
>             $product2 = new Product();
>             $product2->setName('Pineapple Juice');
>             $product2->setPrice('19.99');
>             $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
>             $dm->persist($product);
>             $dm->persist($product1);
>             $dm->persist($product2);
>             $dm->flush();
>      }*
> ```

and I've also created a schema using Command Line  *php app/console doctrine:mongodb:shema:create* command.
Now my schema is created, but I can't persist items. It only has database name and Product collection, which is empty. My Product class contains 3 fields, plus getter and setter functions for protected members. So, please help me understand what's going wrong and why items are not persisted when I run function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code *in the question itself* rather than as an image, and make sure what you're posting is a [MCVE]

Comment: Thank you, It will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is required to add a Route for createAction() in configuration.